# WPF: Examples of using a Style on a Window

Tags: wpf, window, styles, systemmenu

I have created a borderless window style wherein I draw the chrome (Borders, TitleBar, Min, Max, Close, SystemMenu, etc) and I would like to check it against an existing example.  Specifically for the SystemMenu but also in case I missed something.  Does anyone have or know of similar examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended reading:

http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

The [accompanying sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/chrome) contains a couple of templates that you can compare against yours.